# Reply_Message telegram bot api

Tags: telegram-bot

i cannot understand the Reply_to_message method for telegram bot api. here is my code :

```
    <?php

define('API_KEY','My_token');

function bot($method,$datas=[]){
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_KEY."/".$method;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($datas));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch)){
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    }else{
        return json_decode($res);
    }
}

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

if($update->message->text == '/start'){
  bot('sendMessage',[
    'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
    'text'=>'Hello word!'
  ]);
}
```

here when user send /start the bot send hello world text. i wanna user reply to message for sending hello world. i mean when user send /start the bot reply's to message with the text 'Hello world!'

im using webhook.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the key `reply_to_message_id` to the object you are posting and set the `id` of the message you want to reply to as the value.

```
if($update->message->text == '/start'){
  bot('sendMessage',[
    'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
    'text'=>'Hello word!',
    'reply_to_message_id' => $update->message->message_id
  ]);
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work. it just like the first code and does not send as reply.

Comment: The key is called `message_id` (`$update->message->message_id`). I updated my answer

Comment: and sorry do you know how to send sticker via bot on php?

Comment: That's a different question, but check [sendSticker](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendsticker)

Comment: can you give me an example ?